# Separable Variables Coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I hope to get some insights into expressing Partial Differential Equation (PDE) in terms of Separable Variables.

Given the wave equation under Dirichlet Boundary Conditions,
\begin{align}
u_{tt}&=c^{2}u_{xx}, 0<x<l, t>0 \\
u(0,t)&=u(l,t)=0, \\
u(x,0)&=\phi(x), u_{t}(x,0)=\psi(x)
\end{align}
Assuming $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. When we solve the ODE separately, we get $X(x)=B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$. But the solution given, after solving $T(t)$ is
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (C_{n}\cos(c\sqrt{x}t)+D_{n}\sin(c\sqrt{x}t))\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)
\end{equation}
I like to ask, why is $B_{n}$ not necessary to be considered into the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_n$ is redundant, since it can be absorbed into $C_n$ and $D_n$.

That is, if you include $B_n$, you would get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigl( C_{n} \cos(c\sqrt{x}t) + D_{n} \sin(c\sqrt{x}t) \bigr) B_n \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)
\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigl( B_n C_{n} \cos(c\sqrt{x}t) + B_n D_{n} \sin(c\sqrt{x}t) \bigr) \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)
,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
but here you can let $\tilde C_n = B_n C_n$ and $\tilde D_n = B_n D_n$ to get rid of $B_n$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!